# Is Multi-threading required for PyQt4 and Writing to Serial

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, pyqt, pyqt4

My simple Python app uses PyQt4 for its GUI and clicking a `QPushButton` causes the app to send a message via `serial`. GUI elements also update frequently.

**Question:** I did not know how to implement multithreading. Will not having multithreaded process cause the app to be less responsive and less consistent in sending the serial communication especially when a GUI element will be updated at the same time the serial message is being sent?

Answer (score 1):

That depends. Your PC is idle 99.9995% of the time while you type; so it has a lot of CPU power to spend on background tasks. Most people don't notice this since the virus scanner typically eats 5-20% of the performance. But typing or clicking a button barely registers in the CPU load.

OTOH, if you run a long task in the UI thread, then the UI locks up until the task is finished. So from a user perspective, the UI will be blocking while for the serial port, the world will be OK. Overall, this will be faster but it will *feel* sluggish.

Multithreading is generally slower than doing everything in a single thread due to synchronization or locking. But a single thread doesn't scale. Eventually, you hit a brick wall (performance wise) and no trick will make that single thread execute faster.